# Unable to call Controller into routes in laravel 5

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I want to call controller into my route while making custom module. I am having my custom module into the App folder, my module folder such as App/Modules/OEM/

my routes.php (into App/Modules/OEM/routes.php)

```
Route::group(['prefix' => '', 'namespace' => 'App\Modules\OEM\Controllers'], function () {

    Route::get('/welcome', 'OemControllers@welcome');

});
```

my Controller file: (App/Modules/OEM/Controller/OemControllers.php)

```
<?php namespace App\Modules\OEM\Controllers;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Modules\OEM\Models\OemModel;



class OemControllers extends Controller{


    public function __construct (OemModel $OemModel)
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
        $this->OemModel = $OemModel;

    }

    public function welcome(){
        return view('OEM::welcome');
    }
}
```

My Model file: (App/Modules/OEM/Models/OemModel.php)

```
<?php
namespace App\Modules\OEM\Models;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class OemModel extends Model{


    public static function get_url_list() {
       return "this is model of OEM";
    }
}
```

My problem is when I am hitting the URL localhost:8000/welcome, then it will re-direct to home, so unable to call the controller from my routes, and also unable to call model into controller.

Answer (score 0):

You must call the controller in module like this in web.php:

```
Route::get('/welcome', '\App\Modules\OEM\Controllers\OemControllers@welcome');
```